# Timer Event Tick fired before Form_Load Event (VB.NET)

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I have a Windows form with Timer component, by default (design) the timer is enabled, but based on some arguments sent to the form I disable the timer on form_load.

I'm facing a very weird scenario, the Timer_Tick event is sometime fired even before the form_load is fired, this happen with the application minimized for 20 mins for example, then I open the application and trying to open new form, especially on slow systems.

Code as follow:

```
'=============== Code of the form with Timer
Public Sub OpenForm(SomeParams)
        'Set Form Properties
        Me.Show() 'Here the event Form_Load fired
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
  'Some Code ...
  Timer1.Enabled = False/ True 'Based True or false based on parameters
 'Code ...
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
  'Code here
  'The code raise error if form load is not fired, because need info from params ...
End Sub



'=============== Code in the calling form (MainForm)
'Calling the Form
dim obj As new Form1  'I think form this line the Timer1_Tick Fired, before load
obj.OpenForm(Params)
```

When the exception raised, I close the handled exception and try to open the form again it open the form with Timer1 is disabled.

I know the solution is trivial, just make the timer disabled by default, then enabled based on the params, but I want to know WHY the Timer1_Tick sometime is fired before OpenForm Sub and Before Form1_Load Sub !! ?

Many thanks for your time.
Sameh

Comment: What is the value of the Interval property?

Comment: It is unusual but not impossible.  DoEvents() or MessageBox would be good ways to get events to fire out of order.  Yes, the workaround is simple.

Comment: Well, is only a hypothesis. You declare and initalize your timer in the InitializeComponent of the form, called inside the form constructor. This starts immediately your timer, then you exit from the form constructor and before the form show (which raises the Form_Load event) the allotted interval passes. This situation could be increased in the case of an idle app swapped away in the virtual memory on disk. The reloading in physical memory requires more time. You could test if I'm right decreasing the Interval value.

Comment: @Steve: That's exactly it. You should make that an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declare and initalize your timer in the InitializeComponent of the form, called inside the form constructor. This starts immediately your timer, then you exit from the form constructor and before the form shows (which raises the Form_Load event) the allotted interval passes.
This situation could be increased in the case of an idle app swapped away in the virtual memory on disk. The reloading in physical memory requires more time.
You could test my hypothesis decreasing the Interval value.
You should get more Timer_Tick events before the form load event.

Comment: Thanks @Steve, it is exactly as you described, I decreased the interval to 1 and I was able to reproduce, but the I never knew that Timer_Tick fired just after InitializeComponent or constructor, and that was a big bug in my code to make the timer enabled by default. Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Your timer is typically created with the constructor, and the Load event isn't called until the form is actually ready to be displayed.

You should create a custom constructor that accepts your argument on whether to use the timer or not.

Comment: Thanks @Jim, yes it is another great solution, but actually the key was that the timer event is fired in the constructor and I didn't know that obvious think, Steve gave the great description for the problem in the comment and in the answers, thank you all.