# Automatically refresh

Tags: vb.net, listview, timer

I want to ask how to auto refresh/update the listview using timer in vb.net.. Give me an idea or steps, or code. Here's my code in timer:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    conn.Open()
    Timer1.enabled = False
    Timer1.interval = 5000
    Dim strquery As String = "Select * " & _
                           "from software "

    Dim myCommand As New OdbcCommand(strquery, conn)
    Dim myReader As OdbcDataReader
    myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader
    ListView1.Items.Clear()
    If myReader.HasRows = True Then
        'ListView1.BeginUpdate()
        While myReader.Read
            Dim ListView As ListViewItem
            ListView = ListView1.Items.Add(myReader("log_type").ToString())
            ListView.SubItems.Add(myReader("log_desc").ToString())
            ListView.SubItems.Add(myReader("log_details").ToString())
            ListView.SubItems.Add(myReader("log_date").ToString())
            ListView.SubItems.Add(myReader("software_desc").ToString())
            ListView.SubItems.Add(myReader("software_name").ToString())
            ListView.SubItems.Add(myReader("develop_date").ToString())
            ListView.SubItems.Add(myReader("last_update").ToString())
        End While

End Sub
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Timer1.Interval = 1000
    Timer1.Enabled = False
    ListView1.Refresh()
    ListView1.Items.Add(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() + "," + _
                       DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString())
End Sub
```

This timer doesnt work. Is there anything way to auto update or auto refresh a listview?.

Comment: You're disabling the timer in its `Tick` event handler.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13345761/timer-event-tick-fired-before-form-load-event-vb-net

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable the Timer again at the end:

```
Timer1.Enabled = True
```

If not, the timer wont work. `Timer1.Enabled = False` desactivate the Timer.